# scroll to the top of div(not HTML body) of active class in bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using bootstrap carousel to display the content with in a div of fixed height with overflow-y. Now when the content of one element is more and if user scrolls down to read the content and after, if he clicks next, the next div will display from the position where the user left in previous div. But i want to display the next active div from the beginning of the div. I tried different methods where the entire HTML body will scroll up but i want the div to be at its top. So please guide me.

```
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane fade in active current">
    <div class="in-tab" id="style-5">
        <div id="myCarousel1" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item my-Carousel-div active">
                    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
              </div>

              <div id="opop"  class="item my-Carousel-div">
                   <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                                                  </div>

            <div id="opop"  class="item my-Carousel-div">
                   <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<a class="left carousel-control mycontrol" href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left custm-slide-L"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control mycontrol" href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right custm-slide-R"></span>
 </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.in-tab {
    /* height: 580px; */
    height: 424px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#myCarousel1').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    $("div.my-Carousel-div.active").scrollTop();
});
```

also i tried

```
$('#myCarousel1').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#myCarousel1').offset().top }, 'slow');
});
```